# matplotlib intersection of archimedean spiral and circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph, data-science

How would i achieve this in matplotlib and numpy?
I have two coordinates, and trough that get the distance between them

```py
fromCords = (0, 0)  # (x, y), defaults to spawn
toCords = (4800, -5600)  # (x, y), these are the base coordinates
distance = math.dist(fromCords, toCords)  # will be used as the radius for the circle
```

I need to draw one circle and one archimedean spiral on a chart, here is some code that implements the archimedean spiral decently well using matplotlib:

```py
r = linspace(0, a * 10, 360)
t = linspace(0, a * 1000, 360)

x = r * math.cos(math.radians(t))
y = r * math.sin(math.radians(t))

plt.plot(x, y)
```

The circle's radius should be equal to the distance, and the archimedean spiral should keep going until it interesects with the circle, and then go another 50 units to mark the interesection, there should also be a point plotted at the intersection and returned to me as a coordinate so i can work with it within the code.

There is also a margin variable which accounts for the distance from (0, 0) to the beginning of the spiral, so i can make the spiral start not at (0, 0) but further out by the margin.

Another important thing is the amount of turns the spiral makes before reaching the circle.

The cirlce is called the `distanceRing`, while the spiral is the `searchPattern`.

The last important thing to me is the length of the spiral, from its starting point until it finnaly spirals to the circle or distanceRing.

**The spiral is a search pattern and is 256 units wide**, the linewidth should correspond to that and the spiral should wrap around itself perfectly so there is no space between the spiral's turns. Here is an image of what it should look like (though the spiral should not have any gaps it should not overlap either but be perfectly touching): https://ibb.co/N36QV2B
While attempting to implement this on my own, i encountered the problem, that when the shapes get too big or too small, weird issues occur, like they become rageddy and very pointy and i could not think of any way to account for that.

I came up with this code but the problem with it is that is becomes jigged and unsmooth when the numbers are large and it doesnt do anything other than display them anyways which is like 1% of what i need:

```py
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *
import math

# inputs
fromCords = (0, 0) # (x, y), defaults to spawn
toCords = (4800, -5600) # (x, y), these are the base coordinates
toPadding = 100 # because nobody will search 100 blocks near spawn, they will start from 100 to search


# other
# distance = math.dist(fromCords, toCords) # will be used as the radius for the circle
distance = 55



def searchPattern(a): # represented by an archimedean spiral
    r = linspace(0,a*10,360)
    t = linspace(0,a*1000,360)
    x = r*cos(radians(t))
    y = r*sin(radians(t))
    plot(x, y)

def baseLevelRing(radius): # represented by a circle
    theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
    x = radius*cos(theta)
    y = radius*sin(theta)
    plot(x,y)

searchPattern(5)
baseLevelRing(distance)

axis('equal')
show()
```